# Adding to buffer in masm?

Tags: http, buffer, wininet, masm, masm32

I want to retrieve a website content as a string in masm, I am using wininet and the page is requested fine, but when I use InternetReadFile to read the content I am not sure how to put it all in the same buffer, because it's not read all at once.

The code looks like:

```
.data?
Bufferlen dd ?
Buffer db 65536 dup(?)

....


get_page:
    invoke InternetReadFile, hRequest, addr Buffer, sizeof Buffer, addr Bufferlen

    .if Bufferlen != 0
        invoke StdOut, offset Buffer
        jmp short get_page
    .endif

....
```

That would print the entire page in the terminal, but **I want to have the entire page into Buffer**, not only the last chunk read.

In C++ I would use it like this:

```
int BufferPointer = 0;
get_page:
    invoke InternetReadFile, hRequest, addr Buffer+BufferPointer, sizeof Buffer, addr Bufferlen

    .if Bufferlen != 0
        BufferPointer += Bufferlen; <- PSEUDO CODE : This is how I do it in C++
        jmp short get_page
    .endif

invoke StdOut, offset Buffer
```

How can I do that in MASM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
mov ebx, offset Buffer
get_page:
    add ebx, Bufferlen
    invoke InternetReadFile, hRequest, ebx, sizeof Buffer, addr Bufferlen
```

Assuming ebx won't change between the retrieval. You could use also another variable.